# RGB in OpenCV. What does it mean?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Assume we are reading and loading an image using OpenCV from a specific location on our drive and then we read some pixels values and colors, and lets assume that this is a **scanned image**.

Usually if we open scanned image we will notice some differences  between the printed image (before scanning) and the image if we open it and see it on the display screen.

**The question is:**

The values of the pixels colors that we get from OpenCV. Are they according to our display screen color space or we get exactly the same colors we have in the scanned image (printed version) ??

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, openCV doesn't care what the source of the image is, it's just bytes. The pixel values are not reinterpreted, they are whatever they were stored as or as they are in memory

Comment: one thing to mention: OpenCV doesn not apply color formats (like AdobeRGB), afaik it only interprets the images as sRGB.

Comment: @EdChum ... If my question does not make any sense so I hope you can make it with the whole sense it can be. Let me add this scenario. Say we have scanned an image as png lossless format - 300 dpi, and we read and load the same image using OpenCV imgread also as png. So why running the same program in 2 different computers - 2 different display screens give us different pixels volors values?

Comment: Sorry are you saying you loaded the same image on different computers and the values are different? Can you edit your question and clearly explain what you're doing, your observations and code

Comment: @edchum Forget about the code. I am talking about a concept. Printing usually use CMYK. Scanning a printed image and then display it on a screen is mainly passing an image in 3 different devices that may use 3 different color spaces. Print(CMYK) , scanner may use AdobeRGB and display use sRGB. So how to make sure that the color values I have in the printed image are the same on the display, and does imgread in OpenCV or even trying to get the Blue color using for example: img[1][1][0] is giving me the blue color value that is seen on the screen or from the saved scanned image?

Comment: Mark, from your comments I gather that you are asking whether OpenCV applies any color profiles to the data it reads. The answer is no. It reads the bytes as they are in the file. Typically, programs that work with photographs will do the same, and then apply a the monitor ICC profile before showing it on the screen, or the printer ICC profile before sending it to the printer. But even with all the profiles in the world there is no such thing as color constancy. Different devices have different gamuts.

Comment: If you want to work with ICC profiles to ensure some sort of color correctness, check out LittleCMS: http://www.littlecms.com

Comment: @Cris Luengo  Thank you so much. I am aware to ICC profiles. Can you explain how this can help me ?? Maybe in calibration of all devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what you want to do or achieve, here's one thing to mention about color profiles.

The most common color profile for cameras, screens and printers is sRGB, which is a limited color spectrum which does not include the whole RGB range (because the cheap hardware can't visualize it anyways).
Some cameras (and probably scanners) allow to use different color profiles like AdobeRGB, which increases the color space and "allows" more colors.

The problem is, if you capture (e.g. scan) an image in AdobeRGB color profile, but the system (browser/screen/printer) interprets it as sRGB, you'll probably get washed out colors, just because of wrong interpretation (like you'll get blue faces in your image, if you interpret BGR images as RGB images).

OpenCV and many browsers, printers, etc. always interpret images as sRGB images, according to http://fotovideotec.de/adobe_rgb/

Comment: Thanx @Micka

I understand the differences between colors spaces and the wasted data while converting digital files between them and mainly in Scanners, printers, displays. Thank you for your great details too

Print is usually done using CMYK color space. Scanning mostly use sRGB and in new advanced scanners - AdobeRGB is used. Display mostly use RGB. The process of moving the image from print to scanner to display (or even loading it using OpnCV) will lead us to work with different color spaces. So how can I make sure that the blue I have in print is the same blue I have on the display?

Comment: typically, image files have internal information, whether they use sRGB or AdobeRGB, so your program will have to make sure, that the image is interpreted right (opencv won't interpret right!). Not sure about the displays, whether you would have to know your screen and graphics card to optimize the image. Imho, graphic card's RGB is the full range, so it's more about what you do in your program. Or are you asking about, how good your paper image is represented by your screen? This is a problem, since you can't compare both directly, since you again need a camera/scanner with unknown quality.

Comment: maybe you could add a sample workflow/task to your question text, this would make all this a bit less abstract.

Comment: OpenCV has BGR images in memory and will render any memory as if it was a BGR image (not RGB!) to your screen, it represents the same values as they were read from the file and interpreted as sRGB values. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will update the question and add some code so this may help give better explanation about the problem. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't change the extension of the image file, the pixel values don't change because they're stored in memory and your display or printer are just the way you want to see the image and often you don't get the same thing because it depends on the technology and different filters applied to you image before they're displayed or printed..

Comment: What do you mean by not changing the extension of the image? Usually I work with png formats in OpenCV

Comment: @Mark so png is the extension of your file, it defines how your image is compressed

Answer (score 0):

The pixel values are the ones you read in with

```
imgread
```

It depends on the flags you set for it. The original image may have a greater bit-depth (depending on your scanner) than the one you loaded.

Also the real file extension is determined from the first bytes of the file, not by the file name extension.

So it may not be the pixel value of the scanned image if the bit-depths differ.

Please have a look at the [imgread documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread).

Comment: Thank you . I will take a deeper look into the link